# apt-key: command not found

Tags: fedora, apt, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Docker on my Fedora 24 virtual guest OS. I found this command

```
curl -fsSL https://apt.dockerproject.org/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

that should allow to get PGP public key, but got

> sudo: apt-key: command not found

I'm not sure what the problem is, since, `apt-get`, for example, works well.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Any comments from downvoter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Fedora 24, you should use `dnf` to install Docker:

```
sudo dnf install docker
```

This will install [version 1.10.3](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/docker). (Fedora 25 and 26 have more recent versions.)

Alternatively, you can follow [Docker’s instructions for Fedora](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/fedora/) if you want to install their version.

Comment: I got `failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'`. Do you have any idea what could cause this error?

Comment: Not with that — `dnf` will tell you why it failed to synchronize, what does it say in your case? (Look at the rest of the error message.)

Comment: I use new clear Fedora guest OS to get rid of `failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'`. Now `sudo dnf install docker` works fine. As for my question, it seems that `apt-key` supported by Ubuntu only... Thanks for suggesting right command